# Making a UI for Java Calendar

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to create a Java Calendar where the user inputs the year, month, and date and it will tell it what day of the week it is. I can do all of that data crunching, but the problem I have is with the GUI part of the system. So the idea is to have it show the days of the week, and then depending on what day the user inputs, draw an asterisk on each day until it hits the user defined day. For example, lets say the user enters the "2018, 02,15", the calendar should look like:

```
S   M   T   W   T   F   S
                *   *   *
*   *   *   *   *   *   *
*   *   *   *   *
```

So that's what it should look like if it were to be the 15th. So the problem I am having is that I'm not sure how to make it go from Saturday (Far right day) to the next line, because each month on the calendar could start on a different day, and I am also not sure how to do the initial offset to make it go to the first day of the month instead of just starting at Sunday.
The code I have so far draws the asterisks starting on Sunday and keeps going on the same line. (Also, quick note, this is being coded in Ready To Program Java, so it sets c = system.out /system.in by default so some of the code here will look slightly different from traditional Java)

```
int days;
    days = 0;
    c.println ("Enter your day");
    days = c.readInt ();

    c.println ("   S   M   T   W   T   F   S");
    int variable;
    variable = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= days && days < 7 ; i++)
    {
        c.print ("   *");
    }

    for (
```

If anyone knows the solution to this problem, please let me know, and if you need more information, also let me know, because I'm aware I didn't explain it all that well.

Comment: First piece of advice, choose a framework. The basic concept screams "tabular data", which might lead me to [JavaFX Table View](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm). Another solution might be to use a [JavaFX `GridPane`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/gridpane.html). In any case, start by separating the data from the view.  Have some way of modelling what you want which is independent of how you want it displayed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building this UI for a command prompt, correct?

I think you should adjust your loop as so:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= days && days < 7 ; i++)
{
    if(i % 6 == 0)
    {
        c.print("   *\n");
    }
    else
    {
        c.print ("   *");
    }
}
```

Additionally, I recommend using `\t` instead of literal whitespace. `\t` is a quick way to get a tab/4 spaces, and is a little more uniform. Additionally, `\n` could be replaced with `System.lineSeparator()`, which allows for cross-platform (OS) compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
public class CalendarCustom {

    public static String generateCalendarPageWithCrossedDaysToDate(LocalDate date) {
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeekInMonth = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getDayOfWeek();
        StringBuilder calendarPage = new StringBuilder();
        calendarPage.append("   S   M   T   W   T   F   S");
        for (int i = 0; i < date.getDayOfMonth() + firstDayOfWeekInMonth.getValue() + 1; i++) {
            calendarPage.append(i < firstDayOfWeekInMonth.getValue() + 1 ? "    " : "   *");
            calendarPage.append(i % 7 == 0 ? "\n" : "");
        }
        return calendarPage.toString();
    }

}
```

or used IntStream

```
public class CalendarCustom {

    public static String generateCalendarPageWithCrossedDaysToDate(LocalDate date) {
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeekInMonth = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).getDayOfWeek();
        StringBuilder calendarPage = new StringBuilder();
        calendarPage.append("   S   M   T   W   T   F   S");
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(date.getDayOfMonth() + firstDayOfWeekInMonth.getValue() + 1)
                .forEach(i -> {
                    calendarPage.append(i < firstDayOfWeekInMonth.getValue() + 1 ? "    " : "   *");
                    calendarPage.append(i % 7 == 0 ? "\n" : "");
                });
        return calendarPage.toString();
    }

}
```

Used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-02-24");
    System.out.println(CalendarCustom.generateCalendarPageWithCrossedDaysToDate(date));
}
```